# RPi adhoc connection problem with Windows

Tags: pi-2, wifi, windows

I'have created a ad-hoc hotspot with a raspberry pi 2 and original raspberry pi wifi dongle as described at the link

http://slicepi.com/creating-an-ad-hoc-network-for-your-raspberry-pi/

I can connect to Pi's adhoc connection with my macbook without a problem but I cannot connect with my windows computers (I tried 3 different computers) and not connected with another raspberry pi.

what is the problem ? need help

I use raspbian jessie release 8.0 , and Official Raspberry Pi WiFi Dongle

on Windows , ipconfig command not returns valuable details because I don't even connect the ad-hoc network.

[image]

Comment: please share which OS system and which WiFi Dongle are you using. Also Which Version of Debian are you using

Comment: I use raspbian jessie release 8.0 , and Official Raspberry Pi WiFi Dongle

Comment: what does your `ipconfig` on your windows tell you? also try changing your DHCP through this [Link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001048.htm)
I use Linux on my Laptop which is less of a hassle maybe by windows you might need Admin rights

Comment: ipconfig tells nothing , because I can't even connect to network. I change DHCP to obtain automatically and manually both, but it did not work again.

Comment: Can you edit your question into an elaborate step wise question on what have you actually done. I know it takes time but this might help make things more clear. Have you also __Configured the Ad-Hoc on Windows__ ? I mean something similar to [This Post](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/configuring-an-ad-hoc-mode-wlan-with-windows-7.html)

Comment: And [This Link](http://www.tp-link.us/faq-219.html) seems precise. Maybe try this one too!